# Creating object in Java

Tags: java

```
class cricket{
    void bat(){
        System.out.println("sachin");
    }
    public static void main(String ar[]){
        cricket cricket=new cricket();
        cricket.bat();
    }
}
```

output:
sachin

---

The object name is same as the class name. How it is possible that the program is giving correct output? What is the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the Java compiler sees:

```
 cricket cricket=new cricket();
```

it knows that the left side is a variable declaration and the right side is a constructor call because only a class is allowed between 'new' and `(`.

Local variables are saved in a different name space (the "local block scope"), so this works.

But as you noticed, it confuses the reader. That's why the rules for Java say "capitalize class names":

```
Cricket cricket = new Cricket();
```

The upper case letter is completely ignored by the Java compiler but it is a great help for the human readers.

Answer (score 7):

By convention, classes start with capitals, and variables don't. There's nothing that stops the behavior of having a class with the same name as a variable. The only time you can't do that is for reserved words. For example you couldn't do

```
int int = 3; // not allowed
Integer Integer = 3; // allowed, but discouraged
```

If your code were to be more conventional, it would be this:

```
class Cricket{
  void bat(){
    System.out.println("sachin");
  }
  public static void main(String ar[]){
    Cricket cricket=new Cricket();
    cricket.bat();
  }
}
```

Having the variable the exact same as the class can cause some confusion with static methods as well. Consider this:

```
void foo(Runnable r)  throws Exception {
    Thread Thread = new Thread(r);
    Thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(100); // Okay, now WTF does this do?
}
```

Comment: Because there's a variable called `Thread` as well. Now, there's already confusion on using a static method on the variable, but it's compounded by the shadowing of the class name.

Answer (score 2):

This is allowed (object names and class names don't collide), but it's confusing so it's generally considered not a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is where it gets really messy:

```
class bug {
    public static void chirp() {
    }
}

class cricket {
    public void chirp() {
    }
}

//...
cricket bug = new cricket();
bug.chirp();
```

Which `chirp()` is being called, and how do you call the other one?